# How to throw 404 if user is trying to edit link that doesn't belong to him in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I built a Linktree clone following a Youtube video. I had many problems since I was coding in Laravel 8 and his project was in an older version of Laravel.

Now, I don't have a problem on my Local XAMPP server but on my host when I try to open edit.blade.php to edit my links it sends me to a 404 page. That is caused by this code:

```
public function edit(Link $link)
    {
        if ($link->user_id !== Auth::id()) {
            return abort(404);
        }

        return view('links.edit', [
            'link' => $link
        ]);
    }
```

I wasn't able to fix this on a host and now I am thinking if maybe there is a different approach to this code so it works on my host. I am not sure if this code is outdated or something since I am a begginer, so I would appreciate someone's help.

Comment: Do you have any records in your `links` table on your production server/host?

Comment: Did you do any kind of debugging? Using `dd($link->user_id, Auth::id())` is a pretty easy way to see why your code is triggering that `abort(404);`

Answer (score -2):

You're doing a query in the if condition to check if the link was created by the logged in user.
If the link is created by the logged in user then u can access this page otherwise it returns 404 page.
Now if you want to make this page accessible by any authenticated user u can use

```
if(!Auth::user) {
   return abort(404);
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong here `if ($link->user_id !== Auth::id())`?

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your function to this:

```
public function edit(Link $link)
{
    if ($link->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
        abort(404);
    } else {
      return view('links.edit', ['link' => $link]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with `Auth::id()`

Comment: Curious, but how can you mark answer as not useful if you don't even know if it will work for @caktasnino

Comment: `Auth::id()` and `auth()->user()->id` are equivalent, both _should_ be integers too, so if the only thing you changed is `$link->user_id !== Auth::id()` to `$link->user_id != auth()->user()->id`, then this likely doesn't answer the question. Due to that uncertainty, it is being downvoted. If the person asking the question disagrees, and it _does_ fix the issue, they will let you know, and maybe the downvotes will be removed. This is just how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: Hey guys, after all, problem was in the bad database configuration.